# What is the origin Of the expression “there is no denying him”?

Tags: etymology, phrases

When speaking about biological offspring, what is the origin of the phrase “there is no denying him?”

Comment: I’m not aware of any special meaning of this phrase as relating to biological offspring. What meaning are you referring to? Is it used to mean that the kid is the spitting image of ‘him’, for example?

Comment: Context needed.  It does not have an idiomatic meaning different from the (several) literal meanings of the words.

Answer (score 1):

[The verb "deny" has two meanings.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deny) The common one is "say that something is not true", but a second less common meaning "to not allow someone to have or do something". You will find it in phrases like "denied access" and "denied entry".

The phrase "there is no denying him" is simply the literal meaning of the second case. "There is no denying him" means "it is not possible to prevent him getting what he wants".

The etymology of the phrase is therefore the same as the etymology of the word in its second meaning.